# Remove "short" dataframes from a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list, `RT_list`, which is a collection of data frames. I have some data frames that are empty or formed by just few rows.

I would like to remove from `RT_list` all the data frames that are empty or formed by 1 single row.

```
df1 <- data.frame(text = c("Hello I am John","Hello boys","Hello girls","Hello 
   world"), created=c(as.POSIXct("2020-03-18 11:00:29"),as.POSIXct("2020-05- 
   11 11:00:11"),as.POSIXct("2020-01-10 00:00:29"), as.POSIXct("2020-03-19 
   11:11:11")), name=c("John","Anya","Pier","Joe"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(text=character(),
                 created=POSIXct(), 
                 name=character(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
df3 <- df1[c(2,4),]
df4 <- df1[1,]
RT_list<- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over each list element, count the number of rows, and then select those elements with more than 1 row.

```r
RT_list[sapply(RT_list, nrow) > 1]
```

Another option in base is to use `Filter()`.

```r
Filter(function(x) nrow(x) > 1, RT_list)
```

Another way using `purrr`, which is very useful for lists, can be `keep()`.

```r
library(purrr)

keep(RT_list, ~ nrow(.x) > 1)
```

The opposite of this is `discard()`.

```r
discard(RT_list, ~ nrow(.x) < 2)
```